# Methods or models to predict activity of clients of a bank?

Tags: reference-request, banking

I'm a Physicist but I'd like to know if there are some methods or models to predict the activity of the clients of a bank. I heard that banks are interested in this sort of analysis so I got curious about it. The thing is I don't know where to find information about this. Is there a name for such type of analysis? Can you recommend any good book to learn such methods?

---

**EDIT (19/11/15)**

In particular I'm interested in methods to predict the activity of the clients, say we know their banking movements and we want to know *who of them* will no longer be active the next month/year, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Some keywords you might search for will be profiling, RFM, CRM and customer analysis.  clv (or customer lifetime value) might be your best keyword though.

An example CLV calculator: http://www.clv-calculator.com/customer-lifetime-value-formulas/clv-formula/

Here is an interesting clustering model: http://www.iieom.org/ieom2011/pdfs/IEOM068.pdf

An article on how surveys are used to classify customers: http://www.finreghq.com/articles/bank-customer-profiles-and-why-they-are-important-sample-profile-questions/

Again, a lot of good stuff if you search for banking and clv:

https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=banking+clv&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

I hope by active you meant a customer of the bank. In this case you should google "statistical models for customer retention" or just "customer retention". There a lot of interesting articles, for example

http://www.ruthnbolton.com/Publications/RelationshipDurationandSatisfaction.pdf

and

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.7177&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Unfortunately it is my experience that banks do not usually use these models because they are deemed to complicated.